# A question in the rails spec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Today, I use the `factory_girl` instead of the rails fixtures, but i get a problem: 
After I run the command "spec spec" done, the data resets to the fixtures, who can tell me the answer?

thank you!

Comment: you have both in your test ? Factory_girl and fixtures ? or only factory_girls ?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use both factories and fixtures in your project and not running them through the rake tasks: eg `rake spec`, you will need to make sure that you are doing removal of the values from the db by hand. its likely what you are doing is just grabbing an old record in the database and you think the data is being reset. You can verify this by using puts inside your spec to trace the number of records in the db.

`puts MyRecord.count`

You can clear values in an after or before block.

```
before(:each) do 
  Factory(:my_model)
end

after(:each) do 
  MyModel.delete_all
end
```

if you intend to use this model or factory in other spec files, you can add these to global before and after blocks in the spec helper.